# Make Regex accept hyphen/dash in the middle of required string

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I need to create a logfile using powershell.
It needs to have the patients first name, last name and birthdate.
I am currently trying to get the last name to work..

I have a regex that correctly outputs the patients last name, but there are some cases in which the patient has a last name with a dash in the middle.
EXAMPLE: Jonas Bauer-Schönemauer

My current Regex only matches "Bauer", but it's suppposed to match the whole lastname. This is my issue.

Below is my current Regex line.
The first match group is for a random string of numbers and "3101", which is the last names prefix in this medical file.

```
^(\d+3101)(\p{L}+)
```

Here is an excerpt of the file im trying to do this out of (I put the numbers at the beginning of each line, those arent in the file!):

```
1      01380006310
2      014810000722
3      01092063
4      014921802.10
5      0220102GE Healthcare
6      0190103CardioSoft
7      0140132V6.73
8      01630000085271
9      0253101Bauer-Schönemauer
10     0143102Jonas
11     017310321051937
```

Line 9: Last name

Line 10: First name

Line 11: Birthdate (0173103[21.05.1937])

Could anyone help me out?

TL;DR: I need the regex to also match last names with a hyphen in the middle.

Comment: So, do you want to match Line 9, 10 and 11 here? But the last two have `3102` and `3103`, not `3101`. What is the rule here?

Comment: Try `^(\d+310\d)([\w-]+)` or `^(\d+310\d)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 
-I only need to match the full last name in this specific regex line.
The last name always has the same prefix, i created different Regex lines for the first name and birthdate.

-This also gives me the same result as the answer below. It picks up the hyphen, but it stops before the "ö"...

Comment: Not sure what is going on, see `^(\d+310\d)([\p{L}\p{M}]+(?:-[\p{L}\p{M}]+)*)` [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5cd%2b310%5cd%29%28%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5d%2b%28%3f%3a-%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5d%2b%29*%29&i=0253101Bauer-Sch%c3%b6nemauer%0d%0a0143102Jonas%0d%0a017310321051937&o=m)

Comment: It's really weird... Your regex line actually works like i want it to, but my powershell just cant display the "ö".
When i just enter the variable containing the regex match into the console, i get this: Bauer-Sch%nemauer

Comment: If it is a console issue, it is not a real issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should us a character class `[]` :

```
^(\d+3101)([\p{L}-]+)
```

Using `-match` and extracting the second submatch:

```
PS D:\> "0253101Bauer-Schönemauer" -match "^(\d+3101)([\p{L}-]+)"  
True  
PS D:\> $Matches[2]  
Bauer-Schönemauer
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer!
This seems to accomplish what the goal of this post was, but a new problem has now surfaced....
It seems as if it stops right before the "Mutated Vowel", which is "ö" in this case.
Do i also need to integrate something that includes these characters?
INFO: The match this gave me was the following: "Bauer-Sch"

Comment: I tried the regex with a code snippet of my own as you've not posted your code. Result is like expected. I've edited the answer to include the results.